# How can I make the file chosen global?

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a simple GUI program to search read and write a text file.

```
package MyGUIStuff;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multiWinDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel ("File Name:");
        JTextField file = new JTextField (10);
        file.setEditable(false);

        JButton browse = new JButton ("Browse");
        browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
              file.setText(selectedFile.getName());
            }
        }
        });

        JButton search = new JButton ("Search");
        JButton write = new JButton ("Write");

        JButton read = new JButton ("Read");
        read.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
                BufferedReader br = null;

                try {
                    String currentLine;
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile.getName() ));

                    while ((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(currentLine);
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    try { 
                        if (br != null) br.close();
                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
        });


        JButton exit = new JButton ("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        });

        JPanel blank = new JPanel ();
        JPanel first = new JPanel();
        first.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0,5,5) );
        first.add(lbl);
        first.add(file);
        first.add(browse);
        first.add(write);
        first.add(search);
        first.add(read);
        first.add(blank);
        first.add(exit);

        JPanel rPanel = new JPanel ();


        JFrame multiWin = new JFrame ("MultiWin");
        multiWin.setSize(300,130);
        multiWin.setLayout(new CardLayout() );
        multiWin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        multiWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        multiWin.setVisible(true);

        multiWin.add(first);

    }

}
```

My question is how can I make the file chosen in lines 19-22 global? So that my entire program can use it?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You! :D

Comment: Globals are usually a bad idea.  You should pass it to classes that need it.

Comment: What do you mean Pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put all your code in the main() method.

Instead create a panel that contains your GUI components. Then you can create instance variables that are available to the entire class.

For example check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). The `FileChooserDemo` is a working example to get your started.

Not the tutorial example structure will also show you how to structure the code so that the GUI is created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). All code that updates a GUI should be executed on the EDT.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm still in the process of learning Java.

Comment: I told you how to do this. Start with the demo code from the tutorial. Understand how it works and then make changes. You don't learn if you don't try.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class multiWinDemo {
public File selectedFile;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel ("File Name:");
        JTextField file = new JTextField (10);
        file.setEditable(false);

        JButton browse = new JButton ("Browse");
        browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
              file.setText(selectedFile.getName());
            }
        }
        });

        JButton search = new JButton ("Search");
        JButton write = new JButton ("Write");

        JButton read = new JButton ("Read");
        read.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
                BufferedReader br = null;

                try {
                    String currentLine;
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(selectedFile.getName() ));

                    while ((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(currentLine);
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    try { 
                        if (br != null) br.close();
                    }catch (IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
        });


        JButton exit = new JButton ("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener () { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ext ) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        });

        JPanel blank = new JPanel ();
        JPanel first = new JPanel();
        first.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0,5,5) );
        first.add(lbl);
        first.add(file);
        first.add(browse);
        first.add(write);
        first.add(search);
        first.add(read);
        first.add(blank);
        first.add(exit);

        JPanel rPanel = new JPanel ();


        JFrame multiWin = new JFrame ("MultiWin");
        multiWin.setSize(300,130);
        multiWin.setLayout(new CardLayout() );
        multiWin.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        multiWin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        multiWin.setVisible(true);

        multiWin.add(first);

    }

}
```

in this code the `File` is global. But as stated in the other answer, its a bad idea to do all gui code in the main method